# Domino App Service Pack Installation , failed to startup IAM services as tutorial

Tags: node.js, lotus-domino, identity-management, domino-appdev-pack

I had Configure the Domino Credential Store.
I had modified the Domino Proton Server settings that enable client authentication.
I created the Vault ID.
I created the IAM-store.nsf from template with error message.
Error executing agent 'DeleteExpiredDocs' in 'iam-store.nsf'. Agent signer 'Domino Template Development/Domino': You are not authorized to perform that operation

I gave the IAM's functional ID access to the database.

I installed the IAM services for domino with the following message.
[result screen of install domino-iam-service-2.2.0.tgz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgWLp.png)

Since I would like to config the iam-services for my testing server.
I select to setup the pilot mode.

According to the tutorial, https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/iam_landing_page.html

I could access the demo database, with anonymous setting of proton server.
C:\src\domino-db\package>npm run ptest -- read serv.org.com:3003/App\node-demo.nsf -q "Form = 'Contact' and LastName = 'Moody'"

[read the content of demo database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRSUa.png)

[Config the pilot mode successfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBdej.png)

What is doing wrong?
[Error, when try to startup pilot mode of IAM Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZmOP.png)

I have put all the certificates to the folder config/certs,
in which the certificates are created by create_certs.cmd from the tutorial.
And I have convert the ca.crt into ca.pem.
Besides, I also put the keys created by ProtonCA into the config/certs.
[Keys created by ProtonMicroCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYqwO.png)

According to the tutorial, I modified the make_certs.cmd as the following:
[make_certs.cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlFog.png)

[the certificates are posted to the config/certs directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxtl5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your complete setup, a support ticket would help us diagnose this better.   There should be a ca folder in the config/certs directory that contains any root certs you're using (like the ca.pem you have)

Comment: Yes, I have the self-signed root certs with name  ca.pem, and put it into the folder config/certs/ca.